# How can I determine optimal price per clip in Universal Paperclips?

Tags: universal-paperclips

I've started playing [Universal Paperclips](http://www.decisionproblem.com/paperclips/index2.html) as I'm a big fan of clicker games, but I'm having trouble with the Price per Clip and public demand mechanic. There appears to be a degree of randomness involved, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to determine the optimal price, especially as the average per second upgrades seem to fluctuate quite a bit.

Is there a way to determine the optimal price besides simply blindly experimenting with different prices?

Comment: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12850/proposing-a-requirement-to-comment-on-a-post-you-downvote

Comment: @Frank it says page not found for me

Answer (score 3):

I do not have proof, but in my experience while playing the optimal price per clip for income is as low as you can sell without running out of clips.  Try to match supply and demand and that should maximize your revenue (though does mean that you're likely to run out after big marketing improvements, so be prepared to adjust)

Answer (score 0):

basically sell at the cost 1 cent above what makes you run out 
so if selling at 0.11 makes stored paperclips go down to 0 sell at 0.12, if you plan on buying a marketing upgrade make sure to buy wire clippers to go with it or just adjust the price